# Cordova set background image for android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Am working on an android application using cordova and jquery mobile. How to set a background image in this application?i need to put a backgroung image in all pages...

This is my code..See i have only one html page and the below code comes in that html page..also it represents a page..i have 6 pages like this in a single html page..i want to put a background image in these 6 pages.

```
      <div data-role="page"  id="home_page"  data-content-theme="a" style="background-image:url(images/back.jpg)" >  

      <div data-role="header"> 

     <div data-role="navbar"> 
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#about_us_page" id="products" data-transition="none">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#purpose_page" id="projects" data-transition="none">Purpose</a></li>
       <li><a href="#design_page" id="awards" data-transition="none">Design</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
```

Exit

```
<p align="justify">content content.....</p>
```

```
<div data-role="footer"   style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;" class="footer">
       <div data-role="navbar"> 
       <ul>   
       <li><a href="#construction_page" id="about_us" data-transition="none">Construction</a></li>
       <li><a href="#issues_page" id="contacts" data-transition="none">Issues</a></li>
       <li><a href="#share_page" id="locations" data-transition="none">Share</a></li>
       </ul>
       </div>

</div>
```

Here i have given the backgroung image URl in the opening div tag...but it is not working..why is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Put this CSS at the top of every page:

```
<style type="text/css">
body { background-image: url(path/to/your/img.jpg); }
</style>
```

You could also put the CSS rules into an external file and link it on every page like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/your/stylesheet.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-body-b
{
background-image:url(../../images/wtpBackground.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
height:10px;
width:10px;
}
```

To set a background image in JQM you need to override .ui-body-b where 'b' is your theme identifier.